# Calculate column date value from variable and other column date offset

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a project management table with 1000 tasks/records, each with a dynamic `starting_date` and `ending_date` column. The values of those dates are calculated by taking a static project "going-live" date (e.g. `2022-10-01`) and then deducting the `task_offset_days` value of each record (e.g. -211), resulting in the `starting_date` value. The end date is calculated via a `days_to_complete` column with e.g. `60` days value, which if added to the `starting_date` gives me the final `ending_date`.

Example: Live date = `2022-10-01`, offset by `-211` days results in `starting_date = '2022-03-04'`, which plus `days_offset` of `60` results in `ending_date = 2022-05-03`.

Here the issue:

I want to copy the 1000 records to another table and during the process want to update the `starting_date`, `ending_date` value based on another going-live date. How can I do this in the most efficient way considering I am copying and editing 1000 records?

Current copy query:

```
@live_date = '2022-10-01';   // going-live date

INSERT INTO `new_task_table` (
    `property_id`,  // unique identifier, not present in original table
    `status`,
    `task_desc`,
    `phase`,
    `workstream`,
    `task_level`,
    `task_owner_group`,
    `start_date`,   // = live date - offset
    `end_date`,     // = start date + days to complete
    `offset_days`,  // eg. -211 (note: can be below / above zero: -211 or 120)
    `days_to_complete`, // eg. 60
    `created_at`
)
SELECT 
    '31',
    `status`,
    `task_desc`,
    `phase`,
    `workstream`,
    `task_level`,
    `task_owner_group`,
    `start_date`,
    `end_date`,
    `offset_days`,
    `days_to_complete`,
    '2022-01-01 00:00:00'   // date of query execution
FROM `old_task_table`;
```

Comment: In the select part can't you simple adjust the values for the new live date and perform the calculations? Example new_live_date - offset_days as start_date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably simpler than you think. You just pass the values into the `SELECT`

```
@live_date = '2022-10-01';   // going-live date

INSERT INTO `new_task_table` (
    `property_id`,  // unique identifier, not present in original table
    `status`,
    `task_desc`,
    `phase`,
    `workstream`,
    `task_level`,
    `task_owner_group`,
    `start_date`,   // = live date - offset
    `end_date`,     // = start date + days to complete
    `offset_days`,  // eg. -211 (note: can be below / above zero: -211 or 120)
    `days_to_complete`, // eg. 60
    `created_at`
)
SELECT 
    '31',
    `status`,
    `task_desc`,
    `phase`,
    `workstream`,
    `task_level`,
    `task_owner_group`,
    DATE_ADD(@live_date, INTERVAL offset_days DAY) AS start_date,
    DATE_ADD(@live_date,INTERVAL offset_days + days_to_complete DAY) AS end_date,
    `offset_days`,
    `days_to_complete`,
    '2022-01-01 00:00:00'   // date of query execution
FROM `old_task_table`;
```

Comment: @Armitage2k - apologies, made several SQL version assumptions in a row that were wrong. I think `DATE_ADD` is what you want.

Comment: brilliant, thank you very much! Seems like I was indeed overthinking this >.<